# Angular: How to Add a class to Parent when Click on a Child Element

Tags: angular

I have HTML like this

```
<div class="parent"> // This is parent
     <div class="child" (click)="addClassToParent()"></div>// This is child
</div>
```

In Angular, how can I add a new class (such as 'parent-style') to parent when I click on the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
addClassToParent() {
  this.clickEventXXX = true
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" [class.parent-style]="clickEventXXX"> // This is parent
     <div class="child" (click)="addClassToParent()"></div>// This is child
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works well! I have another concern: from this code, and you make the class `parent-style` toggle?  What I mean is when I click on the child, `parent-style` will be added and when I click on the child again, `parent-style` will disappear.

Comment: this.clickEventXXX = !this.clickEventXXX